# Returning element on function without losing prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Anybody know how to create a function that returns an element without losing its prototype?
I am trying to create function to create a new element and return it as an element. This function will have a method to manipulate that element. When I return that element, the prototype won't work. If I don't use `return` in that function, the prototype works properly, but the function returns the `this` object. Look at this code:

```
function ObjEl(tagName, id) {
    'use strict';
    this.node = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (typeof id === 'string' && id.match(/^[a-zA-Z\d\_\-]+$/)) {
        this.node.setAttribute('id', id);
    }

    // return this.node;
}

ObjEl.prototype.atr = function (key, val) {
    'use strict';
    this.node.setAttribute(key, val);
    return this;
};
```

If I uncomment `return this.node;`, when I call `test = ObjEl('div', 'test');` it's returning `<div id="test"></div>`, but this code won't work:

```
test = ObjEl('div', 'test').remove();
```

Comment: Well, you simply can't. You cannot return one object and expect it to behave as an other one.

Comment: You can’t do that. What you can do is recreate all the properties of an element on `ObjEl.prototype`, but that’s just another jQuery and don’t do that. Really.

Comment: @minitech: Yes, I know jQuery and currently i'm using Zepto. But i want to create my own library and the functionality is different with jQuery or Zepto. So, can you show me how to recreate the prototype? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems wierd, but does this acheive what you're trying to do?

```
var ObjEl=function ObjEl(tagName, id) {
    'use strict';
    this.node = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (typeof id === 'string' && id.match(/^[a-zA-Z\d\_\-]+$/)) {
        this.node.setAttribute('id', id);
    }

    // return this.node;
}

ObjEl.prototype.atr = function (key, val) {
    'use strict';
    this.node.setAttribute(key, val);
    return this;
};
var oldObjEl=ObjEl;
ObjEl=function (){
  return new oldObjEl(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is very wrong. A function should not be a prototype of an object.  Whatever you tried to do at the end, it won't do what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Right, that last line was wrong. I removed it. Without it, I've tested the function and it passed his requirement mentioned in the OP. Additional prototype chaining could be used to make the object also pass `test instanceof ObjEl`

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible options

The two best ways (*I know of*) to achieve this kind of behaviour with JavaScript is to either create a wrapping object that manages your dealings with the element(s) in question internally i.e. something similar to jQuery (*see below*); or to extend each element DOM Node directly with your desired extras. e.g:

```
var extend = function( elm ){
  elm.attr = extend.attr;
};
extend.attr = function(){
  // your code here
};
var elm = extend(document.getElementById('div'));
```

You *can* also add to the prototype of certain element's source constructors, i.e. [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) but this will not work cross-browser and may cause problems for other code. It is generally frowned upon to mess with base constructors.

#### The way I chose

In the past I have used the following rough snippet to combine a number of different interfaces — selectively — together into the same object. It is not seasoned code however, and could benefit greatly from proper setup and tear down management — to avoid the risk of memory leaks — because it is basically just a bundle of closures.

```
var harmony = function(){
  if( !(this instanceof harmony) ) { return new harmony(); }
};
harmony.prototype.borrow = function( owner, descriptor ){
  var i, dlen = descriptor.length, item;
  for ( i=0; i<dlen; i++ ) {
    if ( (item = owner[descriptor[i]]) && item.apply ){
      this.borrowMethod( owner, descriptor[i] );
    }
    else {
      this.borrowAttribute( owner, descriptor[i] );
    }
  }
  return this;
};
harmony.prototype.add = function( owner, methods ){
  for ( var i in methods ) { this.addMethod( owner, i, methods[i] ); }
  return this;
};
harmony.prototype.addMethod = function( owner, name, method ){
  this[name] = function(){ return method.apply( owner, arguments ); };
  return this;
};
harmony.prototype.borrowMethod = function( owner, name ){
  this[name] = function(){ return owner[name].apply( owner, arguments ); };
  return this;
};
harmony.prototype.borrowAttribute = function( owner, attributeName ){
  var self = this; self[attributeName] = function(){
    if ( arguments.length ) { owner[attributeName] = arguments[0]; return self; }
    return owner[attributeName];
  };
  return self;
};
```

#### Usage

The above can be used to wrap an element, borrowing methods from the native object, and extending with your own ones. Here's a rough idea of what I mean, this is by no means finalised code.

```
var ElementHarmony = function(elm){
  var self = harmony()
    .borrow( elm, ['innerHTML', 'getElementsByTagName'] )
    .add( elm, {
      getElement: function(){
        return elm;
      },
      attr: function( name, value ){
        if ( arguments.length > 1 ) {
          this.setAttribute( name, value );
          return self;
        }
        else {
          return this.getAttribute( name );
        }
      }
    })
  ;
  return self;
}
/// create our example element and wrap with a harmony instance
var elm = ElementHarmony(document.createElement('span'))
  .innerHTML('<b>hello</b>')
  .attr('style', 'border: 1px solid red')
;
/// find the bold tag inside, and modify it's style
var bold = ElementHarmony(elm.getElementsByTagName('b')[0])
  .attr('style', 'background: orange')
;
/// use getElement() to get back to the original element,
/// when passing to native methods.
(document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(elm.getElement());
```

With the harmony object you can borrow both methods and attributes from an owner object, however the attributes are converted to methods i.e. `innerHTML()`. If you know that your code is only going to be executed on modern browsers you could change this behaviour to utilise getters and setters... but then, that is another story.

#### Hey diddle diddle

Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/K2Xux/